# Compare only two rows in dataframe with each other

Tags: python, list, dataframe, compare

I have a dataframe with a column focus_duration and I want to compare this data pair wise, meaning row zero and one, row two and three, row four and five, etc. If the first integer is bigger than the second, write a 1 in a new column. If it is less, write -1 and if it is equal then 0. I tried by creating a list and comparing one element with the next. But this way it compares element two with element three and element three with element four, what I don't want.

```
a = df['focus_duration'].tolist()
b = []

for i in range(0, (len(a)-1)):
    if a[i] < a[i+1]:
        b.append(0)
    elif a[i] > a[i+1]:
        b.append(1)
```

Comment: Doe the solution has to use list? It can be done using pandas shift and apply which in my opinion might be easier and faster.

Comment: No, it isn't nesseccary for me to use lists

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to check the condition if the number of your row is odd or even.
I'm adding a condition to your own code.
Also, for example, when you use `range(3)` it iterates from 0 to 2.

```
a = df['focus_duration'].tolist()
b = []

for i in range(len(a)):
    if i%2 == 0:
        if a[i] < a[i+1]:
            b.append(0)
        elif a[i] > a[i+1]:
            b.append(1)
    else:
        if a[i] < a[i-1]:
            b.append(0)
        elif a[i] > a[i-1]:
            b.append(1)
```

This code compares zero with one, one with zero, two with three and three with two, so on.